# Why doesn't lord Voldemort just trace and Kill harry in an ambush?

Tags: harry-potter

I'm aware that between books 1-4 Voldemort was vaporized and didn't have a physical body, but why doesn't he just visit Harry after he gained a physical body in books 4-7? Did Voldemort have travel restrictions? Was Hogwarts or Little Whinging protected against Voldemort? I know this would be a plot-twist but there must be a reason...

Comment: Because then it would be a very short and depressing book... other (actual) answers may include the fact that he was trying to keep a low profile at points, and that there are protections in place at the Dursleys and Hogwarts.

Comment: Or just sneak up behind him and shiv him in the back.

Comment: Or wait until he's crossing the road and [run him over with a steamroller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdctnPIR5kA).

Comment: Or trick him into running into a wall by [painting a tunnel on it](https://youtu.be/4iWvedIhWjM?t=8s).

Comment: So HP is aiming somewhere between prison drama and Looney Tunes?  There's a tiny target.

Comment: Definitely a duplicate. They even both mention tracing him.